# continuous data through a socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

lets say I had a socket that needed to send continuous data at random (but small) intervals, lets say about 20 objects a second, for any span of time.

I am for-seeing possible issues that I am not sure how to handle.

1) If I send one object at a time as in example A, may they still arrive in bunches? So as to make it better to do as in example B?

2) Would the thread receiving the data possibly try to read the data before a entire object was sent, thus splitting data, and making another issue I will have to look out for?

pseudo for sending data might look like this

EXAMPLE A

```
void run()
{
    get socket outputstream
    while (isBroadcasting)
    {
        if (myQueue.isEmpty() == false)
            send first object in queue through outputstream

        Thread.sleep(25);
    }
}
```

EXAMPLE B

```
void run()
{
    get socket outputstream
    while (isBroadcasting)
    {
        while (myQueue.isEmpty() == false)
            send all object in queue through outputstream

        Thread.sleep(25);
    }
}
```

and finally read it like this

```
void run()
{
    get socket inputstream
    while (isReceiving)
    {
        get object(s) from inputstream and publish them to main thread

        Thread.sleep(25);
    }
}
```

3) Would this be a viable solution? Is it ok to keep the streams open at both ends, looping and writing/reading data until finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) If I send one object at a time as in example A, may they still arrive in bunches? So as to make it better to do as in example B?

Depending on the type of network you are sending them over, they may definitely still arrive in bunches at the receiving end. In addition, if you are using TCP, the application of [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) may introduce more bunching and apparent delay.

> 2) Would the thread receiving the data possibly try to read the data before a entire object was sent, thus splitting data, and making another issue I will have to look out for?

This is very dependent on your implementation details, and is impossible to answer with the pseudocode provided.

> Is it ok to keep the streams open at both ends, looping and writing/reading data until finished?

Yes, it is perfectly reasonable to use a TCP connection like this for a long period of time. However, your application must be willing to reconnect if the connection is lost for some reason.

Comment: More info on question 2, If I sent them via DataOutputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length) would they likely be read on the other side as a whole? Thank you, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: No they won't. TCP is a byte stream, not a messaging system.

Comment: EJP, I guess what I mean is if I send an array of bytes through, when i read this array on the other side. will all of the bytes from the array have made it through? SO I can build a complete object from them?

Comment: Never mind o finally found it, I need to send a precede every object with 2 flags, one explains the type of object, and the second tells us how many bytes this object is. I then pull that many bytes out of the stream, and then read the next two flags.

Comment: A read can return as little as one byte, or fill the buffer you provide, or anything in between. It can read zero bytes in non-blocking mode. Message boundaries are not respected. 'write()' boundaries are not respected. It is a byte stream. Period.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped put me on the right path. The way i structure my data now is (WHAT KIND OF COMMUNICATION IT IS)(what the Object is)(Object size)(Object)(what the Object is)(Object size)(Object)(what the Object is)(Object size)(Object) etc.